# Do gender table and persons table have an identifying relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I have two tables, one is Persons, and the other is Genders, hence I want to put more than two genders, M, F, Other.

### Persons

- id INT (pk, ai)
- fk(gender_id)

### Genders

- id INT (pk, ai)
- title VARCHAR(255)

What would be the relationship type between Genders and Persons table? Is the relationship between them should be non-identifying or identifying (gender_id has to be primary key too)?

Thanks in advance.
Midori

P.S: (Sorry for grammar mistakes.)

Comment: NO. Gender_id need not to be/part to be Primary Key. It's a  one-to-many relationship between `Gender` and `Person` as there can be multiple persons for a single Gender.

Comment: why do you need the genders table?

Comment: @isaace in my opinion gender is not equal to sex, and some people would prefer 'other' as gender.

Comment: @Harshil MySQL workbench allows defining one-to-many identifying relationships. That's confusing me a bit and I did not find any satisfying answer in any other place.

Comment: I don't think `gender_id` needs to be part of primary key. A non-identifying relationship will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

An identifying relationship would be if the gender_id in the Persons table were part of that table's primary key. In other words, if the gender needed to be part of the way to uniquely identify rows in the Persons table.

In the example you show, the gender_id is merely an attribute of the Persons table. It is not used to identify rows. Therefore it's not an identifying relationship.

Comment: Should it be an identifying relationship? I ended up with the non-identifying relationship with not null constraint, but it seems like I am missing something here.

Comment: There is no need for an additional column to be part of the primary key, unless you need to allow one Person of each gender to have the same `id` value. I assume the `id` column is already a minimal candidate key, so it's the right primary key.